# How to map JSON Object with Java Pojo Class Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

How to map JSON object with POJO class in Spring Boot. I have JSON data as below:

```
    {
    "report": "Cost History",
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "time": [
                {
                    "label": "Total",
                    "name": "total"
                },
                {
                    "name": "2021-12",
                    "label": "2021-12",
                    "direct": null,
                    "populated": false,
                    "excluded": null,
                    "extended": false,
                    "sort_order": null,
                    "parent": -1
                },
                {
                    "name": "2022-12",
                    "label": "2022-12",
                    "direct": null,
                    "populated": true,
                    "excluded": null,
                    "extended": false,
                    "sort_order": null,
                    "parent": -1
                }
                // etc... etc ....
            ]
        },
        {
            "Azure-Services": [
                {
                    "label": "Total",
                    "name": "total"
                },
                {
                    "name": "3000",
                    "label": "Storage",
                    "direct": null,
                    "populated": null,
                    "excluded": null,
                    "extended": false,
                    "sort_order": null,
                    "parent": -1
                },
                {
                    "name": "3001",
                    "label": "Storage Account",
                    "direct": true,
                    "populated": null,
                    "excluded": null,
                    "extended": false,
                    "sort_order": null,
                    "parent": 0
                }
                // .. etc etc
            ]
        }
    ],
    "measures": [
        {
            "name": "total_cost",
            "label": "Total Cost ($)",
            "metadata": {
                "type": "cost",
                "units": "CAD",
                "supports_drilldown": true,
                "label": "Total Cost ($)"
            }
        }
    ],
    "interval": "monthly",
    "filters": [
        "Azure-Services:select:4001,4012"
    ],
    "updated_at": "2022-12-10T06:17:08Z",
    "bill_drop_info": [],
    "visualization_options": null,
    "data": [
        [
            [
                8421.915094617003
            ],
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ],
            [
                null
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                388.6801747227753
            ],
            [
                388.6801747227753
            ],
            [
                0.5626267227750004
            ],
            [
                388.1175480000003
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                872.0477601498656
            ],
            [
                872.0477601498656
            ],
            [
                1.2152157498662994
            ],
            [
                870.8325443999993
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "status": "ok",
    "enable_dp_popover": false,
    "cube_id": "44326_0419_03"
}
```

and I am getting response from my REST Api like this:

```
    {
    "responseMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "status": "OK",
    "statusCode": 1,
    "response": {
        "report": "Cost History",
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "time": [
                    {
                        "label": "Total",
                        "name": "total",
                        "direct": null,
                        "populated": false,
                        "excluded": null,
                        "extended": false,
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "parent": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "2021-12",
                        "name": "2021-12",
                        "direct": null,
                        "populated": false,
                        "excluded": null,
                        "extended": false,
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "parent": -1
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "2022-12",
                        "name": "2022-12",
                        "direct": null,
                        "populated": true,
                        "excluded": null,
                        "extended": false,
                        "sort_order": null,
                        "parent": -1
                    }
                ],
                "Azure-Services": []
            },
            {
                "time": [],
                "Azure-Services": [
                    {
                        "parent": 0,
                        "label": "Total",
                        "name": "total",
                        "direct": false,
                        "populated": null,
                        "excluded": null,
                        "extended": false,
                        "sort_order": null
                    },
                    {
                        "parent": -1,
                        "label": "Storage",
                        "name": "3000",
                        "direct": false,
                        "populated": null,
                        "excluded": null,
                        "extended": false,
                        "sort_order": null
                    },
                    {
                        "parent": 0,
                        "label": "Storage Account",
                        "name": "3001",
                        "direct": true,
                        "populated": null,
                        "excluded": null,
                        "extended": false,
                        "sort_order": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "measures": [
            {
                "name": "total_cost",
                "label": "Total Cost ($)",
                "metadata": {
                    "type": "cost",
                    "units": "CAD",
                    "label": "Total Cost ($)",
                    "supports_drilldown": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "interval": "monthly",
        "filters": [
            "Azure-Services:select:4001,4012"
        ],
        "data": [
            [
                [
                    8486.168096050156
                ],
                [
                    8486.168096050156
                ],
                [
                    9.860766100157399
                ],
                
                [
                    8476.30732995
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    null
                ],
                [
                    null
                ],
                [
                    null
                ],
                [
                    null
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    388.6801747227753
                ],
                [
                    388.6801747227753
                ],
                [
                    0.5626267227750004
                ],
                [
                    388.1175480000003
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    872.0477601498656
                ],
                [
                    872.0477601498656
                ],
                [
                    1.2152157498662994
                ],
                [
                    870.8325443999993
                ],
            ]
        ],
        "status": "ok",
        "updated_at": "2022-12-12T06:38:27Z",
        "bill_drop_info": [],
        "visualization_options": null,
        "enable_dp_popover": false,
        "cube_id": "44326_0419_03"
    }
}
```

**This is AzureService.java POJO class:**

```
public class AzureService {
    @JsonProperty("label")
    private String label;
    
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    
    @JsonProperty("direct")
    private boolean direct;
    
    @JsonProperty("populated")
    private Object populated;
    
    @JsonProperty("excluded")
    private Object excluded;
    
    @JsonProperty("extended")
    private boolean extended;
    
    @JsonProperty("sort_order")
    private Object sortOrder;
    
    private long parent;

}
```

**This is Time.java POJO class:**

```
public class Time {
    @JsonProperty("label")
    private String timeLabel;
    
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String timeName;
    
    @JsonProperty("direct")
    private Object timeDirect;
    
    @JsonProperty("populated")
    private boolean timePopulated;
    
    @JsonProperty("excluded")
    private Object timeExcluded;
    
    @JsonProperty("extended")
    private boolean timeExtended;
    
    @JsonProperty("sort_order")
    private Object timeSortOrder;
    
    @JsonProperty("parent")
    private long timeParent;

}
```

**Below is my Dimension.java POJO class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Dimension {
    
    @JsonProperty("time")
    private List<Time> time = new ArrayList<Time>();
    
    @JsonProperty("Azure-Services")
    private List<AzureService> azureServices = new ArrayList<AzureService>();
}
```

This is my CustomReport.java POJO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomReport{
    private String report;
    private List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
    private List<Measure> measures = new ArrayList<Measure>();
    private String interval;
    private List<String> filters = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    @JsonProperty("updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;
    
    @JsonProperty("bill_drop_info")
    private List<Object> billDropInfo = new ArrayList<Object>();
    
    @JsonProperty("visualization_options")
    private Object visualizationOptions;
    
    private List<List<List<Double>>> data = new ArrayList<List<List<Double>>>();
    private String status;
    
    @JsonProperty("enable_dp_popover")
    private boolean enableDpPopover;
    
    @JsonProperty("cube_id")
    private String cubeId;
}
```

These two classes have properties. I am unable to figure out why these two object showing each others JSON Object response. So is there any JSON property or anything that I need to write before mapping JSON object to POJO?

Comment: I have updated my original JSON response that is coming from external REST API.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You are calling an external REST api using RestTemplate or some other way and want to map json response coming from api to Pojo class?

Comment: I am using RestTemplate to consume external API.

final String uri = "https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/olap_reports/custom/"+reportId+"?client_api_id="+clientApiId;
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<CustomReport>responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, CustomReport.class);

Comment: So the first JSON is what you need, and the second is what you're getting, right? Can you explain where properties like `"name": "2021-12"`, `"label": "2021-12"`, `"name": "3000"`, `"label": "Storage"` are coming from ? This data is not present in the second JSON sample.

Comment: Also, please, explain why the data in the first JSON in arrays `"time"` and "Azure-Services" is partitioned like that (you have only one element in both arrays in the second sample JSON, so it's not obvious from your example)?

Comment: And what about `"measures"` and other properties which are not present in the second JSON? If didn't include them because they are not relevant to the problem, it would be better to remove them from everywhere (from the first JSON as well as `CustomReport` POJO) to **simplify** the question.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I have update my Json Response coming from my application.